# R create ragged df or table

Tags: r

This is probably simple, but I searched and just cannot figure out how to do it in R. I have 3 vectors of character data with different lengths.

```
> Shared
[1] "Cricotopus"      "Eukiefferiella"  "Tipula"          "Thienemanniella" "Diamesa"        
> 
> eDNA
 [1] "Corynoneura"    "Chironomus"     "Amphinemura"    "Dicrotendipes"  "Leuctra"        "Micropsectra"  
 [7] "Antocha"        "Physella"       "Rheocricotopus" "Tribelos"       "Tvetenia"       "Orthocladius"  
[13] "Allocapnia"    
> 
> DNet
 [1] "Acentrella"     "Baetis"         "Paratanytarsus" "Zavrelimyia"    "Callibaetis"    "Centroptilum"  
 [7] "Simulium"       "Pentaneura"     "Pericoma"       "Polypedilum"
```

I want to put them into a df, list, or something so that I can create a table that looks like below. I’m doing this in a loop across dozens of samples to output into a table for each sample.

```
Shared              eDNA                Dnet
Cricotopus          Corynoneura         Acentrella
Eukiefferiella      Chironomus          Baetis
Tipula              Amphinemura         Paratanytarsus
Thienemanniella     Dicrotendipes       Zavrelimyia
Diamesa             Leuctra             Callibaetis
                    Micropsectra        Centroptilum
                    Antocha             Simulium
                    Physella            Pentaneura
                    Rheocricotopus      Pericoma
                    Tribelos            Polypedilum
                    Tvetenia    
                    Orthocladius    
                    Allocapnia
```

Comment: it would help if you told us the purpose of wanting to put this inherently non-tabular into a table format, so that we can provide the appropriate solution (for instance the current answers assume you want to pad the vectors with empty strings — is this suitable for your use-case?).

Comment: These are intended as tables for a report. thanks

Answer (score 2):

A `data.frame` by its intent and definition must have the same length in all of its columns. If some content is shorter than others, the remaining rows in those columns must be padded with something; I tend to prefer using `NA` for this, since even with strings it might be meaningful if a value is `""` legitimately.

```r
L <- list(Shared=Shared, eDNA=eDNA, DNet=DNet)
dat <- lapply(L, `length<-`, max(lengths(L))) |>
  data.frame()
dat
#             Shared           eDNA           DNet
# 1       Cricotopus    Corynoneura     Acentrella
# 2   Eukiefferiella     Chironomus         Baetis
# 3           Tipula    Amphinemura Paratanytarsus
# 4  Thienemanniella  Dicrotendipes    Zavrelimyia
# 5          Diamesa        Leuctra    Callibaetis
# 6             <NA>   Micropsectra   Centroptilum
# 7             <NA>        Antocha       Simulium
# 8             <NA>       Physella     Pentaneura
# 9             <NA> Rheocricotopus       Pericoma
# 10            <NA>       Tribelos    Polypedilum
# 11            <NA>       Tvetenia           <NA>
# 12            <NA>   Orthocladius           <NA>
# 13            <NA>     Allocapnia           <NA>
```

If you prefer empty strings `""` to `NA` here, we can do a simple fill.

```r
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(z) ifelse(is.na(z), "", z))
dat
#             Shared           eDNA           DNet
# 1       Cricotopus    Corynoneura     Acentrella
# 2   Eukiefferiella     Chironomus         Baetis
# 3           Tipula    Amphinemura Paratanytarsus
# 4  Thienemanniella  Dicrotendipes    Zavrelimyia
# 5          Diamesa        Leuctra    Callibaetis
# 6                    Micropsectra   Centroptilum
# 7                         Antocha       Simulium
# 8                        Physella     Pentaneura
# 9                  Rheocricotopus       Pericoma
# 10                       Tribelos    Polypedilum
# 11                       Tvetenia               
# 12                   Orthocladius               
# 13                     Allocapnia
```

If you're curious and also learning the "tidyverse" dialect, it's not a big change, but

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
L <- lst(Shared, eDNA, DNet)
lapply(L, `length<-`, max(lengths(L))) |>
  lapply(replace_na, "") |>
  as_tibble()
# # A tibble: 13 × 3
#    Shared            eDNA           DNet            
#    <chr>             <chr>          <chr>           
#  1 "Cricotopus"      Corynoneura    "Acentrella"    
#  2 "Eukiefferiella"  Chironomus     "Baetis"        
#  3 "Tipula"          Amphinemura    "Paratanytarsus"
#  4 "Thienemanniella" Dicrotendipes  "Zavrelimyia"   
#  5 "Diamesa"         Leuctra        "Callibaetis"   
#  6 ""                Micropsectra   "Centroptilum"  
#  7 ""                Antocha        "Simulium"      
#  8 ""                Physella       "Pentaneura"    
#  9 ""                Rheocricotopus "Pericoma"      
# 10 ""                Tribelos       "Polypedilum"   
# 11 ""                Tvetenia       ""              
# 12 ""                Orthocladius   ""              
# 13 ""                Allocapnia     ""
```

(Yes, I could have used `purrr::map` as well. I think it does not add much to this.)

---

Data

```r
Shared <- c("Cricotopus", "Eukiefferiella", "Tipula", "Thienemanniella", "Diamesa")
eDNA <- c("Corynoneura", "Chironomus", "Amphinemura", "Dicrotendipes", "Leuctra", "Micropsectra",
          "Antocha", "Physella", "Rheocricotopus", "Tribelos", "Tvetenia", "Orthocladius",
          "Allocapnia")
DNet <- c("Acentrella", "Baetis", "Paratanytarsus", "Zavrelimyia", "Callibaetis", "Centroptilum",
          "Simulium", "Pentaneura", "Pericoma", "Polypedilum" )
```

Comment: This worked even better for me than Allen Cameron's list option below. Producing a df let's me do a lot more with the data for tables using packages I already know. thanks, bob

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are just looking for a `list` with a different print method from the standard R `print.list` method. This is easy to do with S3 classes.

For example, if we degine the following functions:

```r
ragged <- function(...) structure(list(...), class = "ragged")

print.ragged <- function(x, ...) {
  x <- Map(`c`, names(x), x)
  wid <- lapply(x, function(n) max(nchar(n)) + 1)
  str <- Map(function(x, n) sprintf(paste0("%", n, "s"), x), x, wid)
  len <- max(lengths(str))
  m <- Map(function(a, b) {
    c(a, rep(paste0(rep(" ", b), collapse = ""), len - length(a)))
    }, str, wid)
  m <- do.call("cbind", m)
  for(i in seq(nrow(m))) cat(m[i,], "\n")
  invisible(x)
}

`[.ragged` <- function(x, i, j) {
  if(missing(j)) return(x[[i]])
  return(x[[j]][i])
}
```

Then we can do:

```r
rag <- ragged(Shared = Shared, eDNA = eDNA, DNet = DNet)

rag
#>           Shared            eDNA            DNet 
#>       Cricotopus     Corynoneura      Acentrella 
#>   Eukiefferiella      Chironomus          Baetis 
#>           Tipula     Amphinemura  Paratanytarsus 
#>  Thienemanniella   Dicrotendipes     Zavrelimyia 
#>          Diamesa         Leuctra     Callibaetis 
#>                     Micropsectra    Centroptilum 
#>                          Antocha        Simulium 
#>                         Physella      Pentaneura 
#>                   Rheocricotopus        Pericoma 
#>                         Tribelos     Polypedilum 
#>                         Tvetenia                 
#>                     Orthocladius                 
#>                       Allocapnia
```

And we get expected subsetting behaviour:

```r
rag$Shared
#> [1] "Cricotopus"      "Eukiefferiella"  "Tipula"          "Thienemanniella"
#> [5] "Diamesa"

rag[1, 2]
#> [1] "Corynoneura"
```

Comment: This worked really well for me and was easy to implement. Thanks so much! bob

Answer (score 0):

Hows about creating a data frame with columns corresponding to each vector and filling in the rows accordingly

```
# Create vectors
    Shared <- c("Cricotopus", "Eukiefferiella", "Tipula", "Thienemanniella", "Diamesa")
    eDNA <- c("Corynoneura", "Chironomus", "Amphinemura", "Dicrotendipes", "Leuctra", "Micropsectra",
              "Antocha", "Physella", "Rheocricotopus", "Tribelos", "Tvetenia", "Orthocladius", "Allocapnia")
    DNet <- c("Acentrella", "Baetis", "Paratanytarsus", "Zavrelimyia", "Callibaetis", "Centroptilum",
              "Simulium", "Pentaneura", "Pericoma", "Polypedilum")
    
    # Find the maximum length of the vectors
    max_len <- max(length(Shared), length(eDNA), length(DNet))
    
    # Create a data frame with empty values
    df <- data.frame(Shared = rep('', max_len), eDNA = rep('', max_len), DNet = rep('', max_len))
    
    # Fill in the data frame with values from the vectors
    df$Shared[1:length(Shared)] <- Shared
    df$eDNA[1:length(eDNA)] <- eDNA
    df$DNet[1:length(DNet)] <- DNet
    
    # Print the resulting data frame
    print(df)

Shared           eDNA           DNet
1       Cricotopus    Corynoneura     Acentrella
2   Eukiefferiella     Chironomus         Baetis
3           Tipula    Amphinemura Paratanytarsus
4  Thienemanniella  Dicrotendipes    Zavrelimyia
5          Diamesa        Leuctra    Callibaetis
6                    Micropsectra   Centroptilum
7                         Antocha       Simulium
8                        Physella     Pentaneura
9                  Rheocricotopus       Pericoma
10                       Tribelos    Polypedilum
11                       Tvetenia               
12                   Orthocladius               
13                     Allocapnia
```