# Replacing a loop with sapply to bind columns when lengths are different

Tags: r

This is silly but I can't recall how to do it. Maybe `do.call` with `cbind`?

In the list `foo` below I'd like to take the `y` column from each of the data.frames a,b,&c to make `bar` with `NA` values when the lengths are different. The output I want is in `bar`. Ideally I could see a tidy solution side-by-side.

```
foo <- list(
  a = data.frame(x=1:2,y=c(5,4)),
  b = data.frame(x=1:5,y=c(3,1,4,5,2)),
  c = data.frame(x=1:3,y=c(8,9,0))
)

bar <- matrix(NA,ncol = 3, nrow = 5)
for(i in 1:3){
  tmp <- foo[[i]]$y
  bar[1:length(tmp),i] <- tmp
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77770757/3358272 for a recent and similar question (with my answer). For here, you can do `L <- lapply(foo, \`[[\`, "y"); lapply(L, `length<-`, max(lengths(L))) |> do.call(cbind, args = _)` for produce a matrix like your `bar`; replace the `do.call(..)` with `data.frame()` to make it a similar frame.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `do.call` + `cbind` like below

```
> L <- max(sapply(foo, nrow))

> do.call(cbind, lapply(foo, \(u) `length<-`(u$y, L)))
      a b  c
[1,]  5 3  8
[2,]  4 1  9
[3,] NA 4  0
[4,] NA 5 NA
[5,] NA 2 NA
```

Or, you can try `merge` the dataframes via `Reduce`

```
> unname(as.matrix(Reduce(\(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "x", all = TRUE), foo)[-1]))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    3    8
[2,]    4    1    9
[3,]   NA    4    0
[4,]   NA    5   NA
[5,]   NA    2   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [R create ragged df or table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77770757/3358272), the difference being how the initial data is defined.

```r
L <- lapply(foo, `[[`, "y")
lapply(L, `length<-`, max(lengths(L))) |>
  do.call(cbind, args = _)
#       a b  c
# [1,]  5 3  8
# [2,]  4 1  9
# [3,] NA 4  0
# [4,] NA 5 NA
# [5,] NA 2 NA
```

produces a matrix with the same values (but with column names now) as `bar`. If you need a `data.frame` instead, replace the `do.call(..)` with `data.frame(..)`:

```r
lapply(L, `length<-`, max(lengths(L))) |>
  data.frame()
#    a b  c
# 1  5 3  8
# 2  4 1  9
# 3 NA 4  0
# 4 NA 5 NA
# 5 NA 2 NA
```

Alternatively (and perhaps *severely*), we can work on the frames in-list and somehow combine them later.

```r
lapply(foo, function(dat)
    lapply(dat, `length<-`, max(sapply(foo, nrow))) |> data.frame()) |>
  do.call(cbind, args = _)
#   a.x a.y b.x b.y c.x c.y
# 1   1   5   1   3   1   8
# 2   2   4   2   1   2   9
# 3  NA  NA   3   4   3   0
# 4  NA  NA   4   5  NA  NA
# 5  NA  NA   5   2  NA  NA
```

Though clearly this has different names and too many columns ...

Answer (score 0):

A quasi tidy approach, using `tibble` and `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(sapply(foo, "[", "y")) %>% 
  unnest_wider(1, names_sep="") %>% 
  t() %>% 
  unname()
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    3    8
[2,]    4    1    9
[3,]   NA    4    0
[4,]   NA    5   NA
[5,]   NA    2   NA
```

or, without the `apply` loop (with names for fun)

```
tibble(foo) %>% 
  unnest_wider(1, transform=as.vector) %>% 
  select(-x) %>% 
  unnest_wider(1, names_sep="") %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair=\(x) names(foo))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5     3     8
2     4     1     9
3    NA     4     0
4    NA     5    NA
5    NA     2    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another Tidyverse-based approach would be through `purrr::list_rbind()` and `tidyr::pivot_wider()`:

```r
foo <- list(
  a = data.frame(x=1:2,y=c(5,4)),
  b = data.frame(x=1:5,y=c(3,1,4,5,2)),
  c = data.frame(x=1:3,y=c(8,9,0))
)

purrr::list_rbind(foo, names_to = "src") |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = src, values_from = y)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>       x     a     b     c
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     3     8
#> 2     2     4     1     9
#> 3     3    NA     4     0
#> 4     4    NA     5    NA
#> 5     5    NA     2    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>